# Using Objective-C pod "Kingpin" in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6, mapkit

I am playing around with a mapping iOS app, using MapKit.

I would like to use Kingpin as a clustering library but I am using swift and the guide is objective-c only.
I create the cluster controller

```
var clusterController = KPClusteringController()
```

and add the delegate to the View Controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, KPClusteringControllerDelegate {
```

However I can't seem to be able to call the initWithMapView method, what am I doing wrong?

PS: the library should be imported correctly as both KPClusteringController and KPClusteringControllerDelegate are suggested by Xcode.

EDIT

I should be able to initialise the clustering manager like this

```
self.clusteringController = [[KPClusteringController alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView]
```

However I have no idea how to do it in Swift :/ I would expect Xcode to give me a suggestion, but something might be loading properly.

Full kingpin doc here https://github.com/itsbonczek/kingpin

Comment: Can you show the code that's failing?

Comment: Thanks Caleb, I updated the question,  full doc here https://github.com/itsbonczek/kingpin

Answer (score 1):

> However I have no idea how to do it in Swift :/

As described in the *Initialization* section of [*Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html), in Swift you do this:

```
clusteringController = KPClusteringController(mapView:mapView)
```

The fact that you're using CocoaPods to manage this framework doesn't have any bearing on the situation. You just need to learn enough about Swift to translate from Objective-C.